# VS Code run button doesnt work when using def python3

Tags: python-3.x, function, visual-studio-code

As the title says when I try to run my code in vs code with the "run code button" when it contains a function like

```
    def plus(x,y):
        return x+y
```

it doesn't run. However, if I just use for example

```
    print("hello")
```

it runs smoothly and prints hello as expected.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: look into `interactive Python`, it will execute your code and then you can use the bottom line in the interactive window to call the function

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
def plus(x,y):
    return x+y
print(plus(1, 2))
```

`plus` is just a function, and no function caller. Then `print("helloword")` is a statement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer however i was looking for a way to make it run and then from the terminal write "plus(4,5)" and expect the result to be 9 and that doesnt work

Comment: @Felixösund You may want to look at the `eval()` and `input()` function